# How to create column and copy another column into the newly created one

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, copy

I'm trying to achieve a simple task, I create a new column in a table and immediately afterwards try to copy a value of some other column in the same table into the new created column but I got a

> Invalid column name 'COMMENT_TMP'.
>   error

The SQL is

Invalid column name 'COMMENT_TMP'.

```
ALTER TABLE TASK_COMMENT ADD COMMENT_TMP text;
UPDATE TASK_COMMENT SET TASK_COMMENT.COMMENT_TMP = COMMENT;
```

Comment: (Unless you are still on SQL Server 2000) don't use the `text` datatype. It is deprecated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You first need to send the`ALTER` batch to the server before executing the `UPDATE`. Add [`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) after the `ALTER` statement

Answer (score 15):

Add the batch delimiter and the table name in your update statement.

```
ALTER TABLE TASK_COMMENT ADD COMMENT_TMP text;

GO

UPDATE TASK_COMMENT SET COMMENT_TMP = COMMENT;
```